# Why there is import of bootstrap module in the main.js file?

Tags: ecmascript-6, aurelia

I saw in most of the setups **import 'bootstrap';** in the Aurelia main.js file.
The question is why is that? Is it give us some extra usage of bootstrap across our app and cant we include it in app.js for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line loads bootstrap's javascript files. None of the functionality is needed in `main.js`, but it is needed for things like the responsive menubar to work, so `import 'bootstrap';` is used. Doing this just loads and runs the file, but doesn't actually pull any funtionality in to the current module.

We do the same thing to load the `fetch` polyfill with `import 'fetch';`.